# How To Read A File in php wrappers as utf-16

Tags: php, character-encoding, php-stream-wrappers

Is there a way to read a file in a specific character encoding like UTF-16 using PHP's stream wrappers, in the same way I can read a base64-encoded file using `php://filter/convert.base64-decode/resource=file.txt`?

Comment: use this `mb_convert_encoding($content, 'utf-16')`

Comment: Great , but I want to use it with wrappers like:php://filter/resource=somefile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP strings don't know anything about encodings, so PHP file functions essentially treat every file as a binary file.

If you know that a set of bytes should be read as UTF-16, you can convert it *to* some other encoding of your choice (here using UTF-8 as an example) using any of these (depending which extensions you have installed):

```
// Requires ext/iconv; arguments are From, To, String
$utf8_string = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $utf16_string);
// Requires ext/mbstring; arguments are String, To, From
$utf8_string = mb_convert_encoding($utf16_string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
// Requires ext/intl; arguments are String, To, From
$utf8_string = UConverter::transcode($utf16_string, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
```

Conversely, if you know that the string is in some particular encoding (again, using UTF-8 as an example), and *want* it to be UTF-16, you would put things in the opposite order:

```
// Requires ext/iconv; arguments are From, To, String
$utf16_string = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $utf8_string);
// Requires ext/mbstring; arguments are String, To, From
$utf16_string = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
// Requires ext/intl; arguments are String, To, From
$utf16_string = UConverter::transcode($utf8_string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
```

In both cases, the resulting string is just a different sequence of bytes; other PHP functions still won't "know" what it "means".

---

The "iconv" extension also provides [a conversion filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filters.convert.php#filters.convert.iconv) which runs the equivalent of the `iconv` function as a file or stream is being read. So if you have a file which you know should be read as UTF-16, and want its contents as UTF-8, you could write:

```
$fp = fopen('php://filter/convert.iconv.utf-16.utf-8/resource=/path/to/utf16-file.txt', 'r');
$first_10_bytes_of_utf16_converted_to_utf8 = fgets($fp, 10);
fclose($fp);
```

Or the reverse - a UTF-8 file which you want to read as UTF-16:

```
$fp = fopen('php://filter/convert.iconv.utf-8.utf-16/resource=/path/to/utf8-file.txt', 'r');
$first_10_bytes_of_utf8_converted_to_utf16 = fgets($fp, 10);
fclose($fp);
```

Again, it's important to remember that PHP is working in *bytes*, so the `fgets` calls above may result in corrupted text because the 10th byte wasn't the end of a Unicode code point.

Comment: Is there a way to use one of these functions in php wrappers like:php://filter/resource=file.php

Comment: I can use it to convert the contents to upper or lower case :php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=file.txt

Comment: @AliSaleh I hadn't understood from your question that that is what you wanted; I have updated my answer appropriately, and also made some edits to your question to make it easier for future readers to understand.

Comment: Brother you don't know how this helped me lots ,Thank you so much